# Couchbase/Membase: Moxi proxy downstream timeout SERVER_ERROR

Tags: couchbase, membase

I have a live Couchbase cluster on two Amazon EC2 instances (version 1.8.0) and about 5 application servers each running PHP with moxi clients on them. Once in a while, Moxi will return a `SERVER_ERROR` when attempting to access data. This happens about once every few minutes on average. The cluster processes about 500 operations per second.

After inspecting the moxi logs (with -vvv enabled), I notice the following at around the time I get a `SERVER_ERROR`:

```
2013-07-16 03:07:22: (cproxy.c.2680) downstream_timeout
2013-07-16 03:07:22: (cproxy.c.1911) 56: could not forward upstream to downstream
2013-07-16 03:07:22: (cproxy.c.2004) 56: upstream_error: SERVER_ERROR proxy downstream timeout^M
```

I tried increasing the downstream timeout in the moxi configs from 5000 to 25000, but that doesn't help at all. The errors still happen just as frequently.

Can someone suggest any ideas for me to discover the cause of the problem? Or if there's some likely culprit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SERVER_ERROR proxy downstream timeout
>
> In this error response, moxi reached a timeout while waiting for a
>   downstream server to respond to a request. That is, moxi did not see
>   any explicit errors such as a connection going down, but the response
>   is just taking too long. The downstream connection will be also closed
>   by moxi rather than putting the downstream connection back into a
>   connection pool. The default downstream_timeout configuration is 5000
>   (milliseconds).

Pretty straight forward error, but it can be caused by a few possible things.

try getting the output of "stats proxy" from moxi:

```
echo stats proxy | nc HOST 11211
```

obviously you have already figured out that you are concerned with these settings:

```
STAT 11211:default:pstd_stats:tot_downstream_timeout xxxx
STAT 11211:default:pstd_stats:tot_wait_queue_timeout nnnnn
```

your downstream_timeout as you've said should appear as 5000

but also check out:

```
STAT 11211:default:pstd_stats:tot_downstream_conn_queue_timeout 0
```

from URL:

http://www.couchbase.com/docs/moxi-manual-1.8/moxi-dataflow.html

pretty much a perfect walk through of the way moxi operates.

> To understand some of the configurable command-line flags in moxi
>   (concurrency, downstream_max, downstream_conn_max, downstream_timeout,
>   wait_queue_timeout, etc), it can be helpful to follow a request
>   through moxi...
>
> The normal flow of data for moxi is as follows:
>
> A client connects
>
> A client creates a connection (an upstream conn) to moxi. 
>   moxi's -c command-line parameter ultimately controls the limits on 
>   the maximum number of connections.
>
> In this -c parameter, moxi inherits the same behavior as memcached, 
>   and will stop accept()'ing client connections until
>   existing connections are closed. When the count of existing
>   connections drops below the -c defined level, moxi will accept() more
>   client connections.
>
> The client makes a request, which goes on the wait queue
>
> Next, the client makes a request — such as simple single-key 
>   command (like set, add, append, or a single-key get).
>
> At this point, moxi places the upstream conn onto the tail of a wait 
>   queue. moxi's wait_queue_timeout parameter controls how long an
>   upstream conn should stay on the wait queue before moxi times it out
>   and responds to the client with a SERVER_ERROR response.
>
> The concurrency parameter
>
> Next, there's a configurable max limit to how many upstream conn 
>   requests moxi will process concurrently off the head of the wait
>   queue. This configurable limit is called concurrency. (This formerly
>   used to be known, perhaps confusingly, as downstream_max. For
>   backwards compatibility, concurrency and downstream_max configuration
>   flags are treated as synonyms.)
>
> The concurrency configuration is per-thread and per-bucket. That 
>   is, the moxi process-level concurrency is actually concurrency X
>   num-worker-threads X num-buckets.
>
> The default concurrency configuration value is 1024. This means moxi 
>   will concurrently process 1024 upstream connection requests from
>   the head of the wait queue. (There are more queues in moxi, however,
>   before moxi actually forwards a request. This is discussed in later
>   sections.)
>
> Taking the concurrency value of 1024 as an example, if you have 4 
>   worker threads (the default, controlled by moxi's -t parameter) and 1
>   bucket (what most folks start out with, such as the "default" bucket),
>   you'll have a limit of 1024 x 4 x 1 or 4096 concurrently processed
>   client requests in that single moxi process.
>
> The rationale behind the concurrency increase to 1024 for moxi's 
>   configuration (it used to be much lower) is due to the evolving design
>   of moxi. Originally, moxi only had the wait queue as its only internal
>   queue. As more, later-stage queues were added during moxi's history,
>   we found that getting requests off the wait queue sooner and onto the
>   later stage queues was a better approach. We'll discuss these
>   later-stage queues below.
>
> Next, let's discuss how client requests are matched to downstream connections.
>
> Key hashing
>
> The concurrently processed client requests (taken from the head 
>   of the wait queue) now need to be matched up with downstream connections
>   to the Couchbase server. If the client's request comes with a key
>   (like a SET, DELETE, ADD, INCR, single-key GET), the request's key is
>   hashed to find the right downstream server "host:port:bucket" info.
>   For example, something like — "memcache1:11211:default". If the
>   client's request was a broadcast-style command (like FLUSH_ALL, or a
>   multi-key GET), moxi knows the downstream connections that it needs to
>   acquire.
>
> The downstream conn pool
>
> Next, there's a lookup using those host:port:bucket identifiers into 
>   a downstream conn pool in order to acquire or reserve the
>   appropriate downstream conns. There's a downstream conn pool per
>   thread. Each downstream conn pool is just a hashmap keyed by
>   host:port:bucket with hash values of a linked-list of available
>   downstream conns. The max length of any downstream conn linked list is
>   controlled by moxi's downstream_conn_max configuration parameter.
>
> The downstream_conn_max parameter
>
> By default the downstream_conn_max value is 4. A value of 0 means no limit.
>
> So, if you've set downstream_conn_max of 4, have 4 worker threads,
>   and have 1 bucket, you should see moxi create a maximum of 4
>   X 4 X 1 or 16 connections to any Couchbase server.
>
> Connecting to a downstream server
>
> If there isn't a downstream conn available, and the 
>   downstream_conn_max wasn't reached, moxi creates a downstream conn as
>   needed by doing a connect() and SASL auth as needed.
>
> The connect_timeout and auth_timeout parameters
>
> The connect() and SASL auth have their own configurable timeout 
>   parameters, called connect_timeout and auth_timeout, and these
>   are in milliseconds. The default value for connect_timeout is 400
>   milliseconds, and the auth_timeout default is 100 milliseconds.
>
> The downstream conn queue
>
> If downstream_conn_max is reached, then the request must wait until a 
>   downstream conn becomes available; the request therefore is
>   placed on a per-thread, per-host:port:bucket queue, which is called a
>   downstream conn queue. As downstream conns are released back into the
>   downstream conn pool, they will be assigned to any requests that are
>   waiting on the downstream conn queue.
>
> The downstream_conn_queue_timeout parameter
>
> There is another configurable timeout, downstream_conn_queue_timeout, 
>   that defines how long a request should
>   stay on the downstream conn queue in milliseconds before timing out.
>   By default, the downstream_conn_queue_timeout is 200 milliseconds. A
>   value of 0 indicates no timeout.
>
> A downstream connection is reserved
>
> Finally, at this point, downstream conn's are matched up for the 
>   client's request. If you've configured moxi to track timing histogram
>   statistics, moxi will now get the official start time of the request.
>   moxi now starts asynchronously sending request message bytes to the
>   downstream conn and asynchronously awaits responses.
>
> To turn on timing histogram statistics, use the "time_stats=1" 
>   configuration flag. By default, time_stats is 0 or off.
>
> The downstream_timeout parameter
>
> Next, if you've configured a downstream_timeout, moxi starts a timer 
>   for the request where moxi can limit the time it will spend
>   processing a request at this point. If the timer fires, moxi will
>   return a "SERVER_ERROR proxy downstream timeout" back to the client.
>
> The downstream_timeout default value is 5000 milliseconds. If moxi sees 
>   this time elapse, it will close any downstream connections that
>   were assigned to the request. Due to this simple behavior of closing
>   downstream connections on timeout, having a very short
>   downstream_timeout is not recommended. This will help avoid repetitive
>   connection creation, timeout, closing and reconnecting. On an
>   overloaded cluster, you may want to increase downstream_timeout so
>   that moxi does not constantly attempt to time out downstream
>   connections on an already overloaded cluster, or by creating even more
>   new connections when servers are already trying to process requests on
>   old, closed connections. If you see your servers greatly spiking, you
>   should consider making this adjustment.
>
> Responses are received
>
> When all responses are received from the downstream servers for a request (or the
>   downstream conn had an error), moxi asynchronously
>   sends those responses to the client's upstream conn. If you've
>   configured moxi to track timing histogram statistics, moxi now tracks
>   the official end time of the request. The downstream conn is now
>   released back to the per-thread downstream conn pool, and another
>   waiting client request (if any) is taken off the downstream conn queue
>   and assigned to use that downstream conn.
>
> Backoff/Blacklisting
>
> At step 6, there's a case where a connect() attempt might fail. Moxi
>   can be configured to count up the number of connect() failures for a
>   downstream server, and will also track the time of the last failing
>   connect() attempt.
>
> With the connect() failure counting, moxi can be configured to
>   blacklist a server if too many connect() failures are seen, which is
>   defined by the connect_max_errors configuration parameter. When more
>   than connect_max_errors number of connect() failures are seen, moxi
>   can be configured to temporarily stop making connect() attempts to
>   that server (or backoff) for a configured amount of time. The backoff
>   time is defined via the connect_retry_interval configuration, in
>   milliseconds.
>
> The default for connect_max_errors is 5 and the connect_retry_interval
>   is 30000 millisecods, that is, 30 seconds.
>
> If you use connect_max_errors parameter, it should be set greater than
>   the downstream_conn_max configuration parameter.